# Postgres Select one record per matching condition

Tags: postgresql

I have some issues while trying to get only one record per matching condition..

Let's suppose I have *Certifications* table with the following columns:
Id, EmployeeId, DepartmentId, CertificationTitle, PassedDate

An employee can have more then one record in this table but I need to get only one record per employee (based on latest PassedDate)

```
SELECT Id, EmployeeId, CertificationTitle 
FROM certifications c 
ORDER BY EmployeeId, PassedDate DESC
```

From this select I need somehow to get only the first record for each EmployeeId.
Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this, Is it possible?
The Id is the Primary Key on the table, so it is different on each record.
I need to keep all this columns specified in the Select query.
The Group By didn't worked for me, or maybe I did it wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`. This returns exactly the first ordered record of the group. You ordered correctly by `PassedData DESC` to get the most recent record first. The group for `DISTINCT ON`, naturally, is `EmployeeID`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (EmployeeId),
    Id, 
    EmployeeId, 
    CertificationTitle 
FROM certifications c 
ORDER BY EmployeeId, PassedDate DESC
```